# Spring Cloud Contract : Write Contract Test for multiple consumer with different or partially different expectations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

We are doing consumer driven testing using spring-cloud-contract. I have two consumers (services) and one producer service. All of them are in different repositories. 
 The producer has an api e.g. - /get/product/123. Each consumer has different requirements. So, I created two folders and put a getProduct.groovy file in each folder. It looks something like below:

`contracts
│   ├── consumerA
│   │   ├── GetProduct.groovy
│   ├── consumerB
│   │   ├── GetProduct.groovy`

Both groovy files contain different body and generate stubs in the respective folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the `stubsPerConsumer` feature to work, you need to make sure you set its flag to true in the `StubRunner` setup in your consumer integration tests, like so:

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "yourids", repositoryRoot = "yourrepository",
stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE,stubsPerConsumer = true)
```

Comment: Well this was not really my question. But I would still mark it accepted because I could not even find this in my first attempt. I had read through a lot of git hub issues to come to the point of your answer. I will also change my question a little.

Comment: I assumed that was causing the problem. Do you still have this issue after applying that change?

Comment: No I was able to figure it out. But thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Adding more to @OlgaMaciaszek,

There is possiblity of specifying `consumerName` which must be the same as the sub-folder name in producers `/contract` folder.

One may choose to skip providing the `consumerName` by using application name specified in application.yaml. But this also means that the subfolder in producer's contract folder must be same as the application name of consumer.